# In Apache Solr, I have used txt_general field type to store date time format. But when I try to sort this field it doesn't get sorted

Tags: solr

Eg:

**timestmp_t:"2016-02-11 12:00:00"  (_t for txt_general)**
When I try to sort this field in ASC or DESC order, I dont get sorted results.

Can anyone help me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are using txt_genral I am assuming that this uses a Standard Tokenizer or Keyword Tokenizer, this tokenizer's are for text not for date.
Now here I am we use two things one is the direct method and other is by using copy field.
1)Direct Method
Here You can directly specify date field type in

```
<fieldType name="tdate" class="solr. TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

<field name="timestamp_t" type="tdate"/>
```

2)Copy Field Method

```
<fieldType name="tdate" class="solr. TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

<field name="copy_timestamp_t" type="tdate"/>

<copyField source="copy_timestamp_t" dest="timestamp_t" maxChars="30000" />
```

I will recommend to use 1 method are index it again.

Comment: Yes I know, but even if they are for text only,shouldn't it be sorting numbers as well by treating them normal text?

Comment: And I haven't created any schema.xml for my collection in solr. I preferred using dynamic fields. And I dont want to use timestamp format that contains Z,T in it, therefore I used it as txt_general.

Comment: If you're using a text field, the field will be tokenized. The underlying information in the index is not what you're putting in, so when you sort - things get weird. "2016-02-11 12:00:00" will be, depending on your tokenizer, split into "2016", "02", "11", "12", "00", "00". If you try to sort by those values, everything falls apart. Use a string field (StrField) (which doesn't have tokenization) or a proper datefield.